# Connecting wordpress website to remote database

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress website hosted on godaddy and would like to connect it to a remote mysql database. Is it possible to have this website connected with 2 databases?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible on GoDaddy shared hosting, you have to have dedicated hosting to get access to a remote database.

(I know because I tried and contacted their support, and this is what they said)

Comment: Theres not any special requirement for connecting to remote database, they might said this to make your database open for remote connection :)

Comment: I'm aware there's no special requirement, but they actively block outbound DB requests.

Comment: Unless it's changed recently, you have the option when creating a database to make the database available from the outside.  This way you can connect to the database from an outside server (or something like HeidiSQL running locally on your PC), without having to connect through localhost.  But as far as database connections go, Ankit Pise has it correct in saying that MySQL doesn't care where the database lives that it talks to.  As long as the server running the PHP script is able to talk to MySQL on a different server, it's all the same to it.

Comment: @Quixrick I think you've got it backwards, he wants to have his site hosted on GoDaddy, and the database hosted remotely.  I'm saying that's not possible (at least not without dedicated hosting).

Comment: GoDaddy is not the best host as they do not let you connect native wordpress to remote host.

Answer (score 0):

Theres nothing special you have to do for it.

Just put login credentials of remote db server & make sure user has remote login allowed.

and make following changes in wp-config.php

```
/* MySQL settings */
define( 'DB_NAME',     'database_name_here' );
define( 'DB_USER',     'username_here' );
define( 'DB_PASSWORD', 'password_here' );
define( 'DB_HOST',     'SERVER_PORT/DOMAIN HERE' );
define( 'DB_CHARSET',  'utf8' );
```

why would you conntect website with 2 databases?

Comment: I will try this out then. Actually I want to use my remote database only thus I need to remove the database which automatically is connected to.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't get it to work through 3306, there are a couple of alternatives.

The better of the two options is to use SSH.  If GoDaddy supports this, try connecting to your remote server via port 22 and then log in to MySQL as the localhost user.

The other option is to  set up a proxy to handle the request over port 80 or 443.  A Google search turned up several to pick from (like this one http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4000-PHP-Execute-remote-MySQL-queries-across-the-Web.html), but as I haven't used any of them, I cannot recommend one over another.

Maybe some of the folks here can recommend one that works well.